# FullSimplify cascades too much/groups variables too eagerly

Tags: simplifying-expressions

This is something FullSimplify will give:

$$\frac{n (s+\text{s2})-\text{a1} g}{\text{a1} (g-\text{a2} s)+s (s+\text{s1}) (s+\text{s2})}$$

I could find better examples where FullSimplify cascades variables into 4-5 parentheses, it is clearly difficult to understand what you are looking at.

What would you advise?

Comment: Try Together[...]

Comment: Take a look at `ComplexityFunction` to understand why `Simplify` does this.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I find this result intuitive  ...  Can you give an example how would you like the result to look like? ( I feel it is just a matter of opinions here ... )